# Quebec GIS Data

Tags: data, topography, canada

I'm looking for basic political borders for the province of Quebec, as well as property parcel data and topography. Any suggestions for inexpensive/free data?

Comment: what research have you done?

Comment: I have consulted their natural resources page and a few other government-based sites.

Answer (score 3):

Quebec is big you can find open data by individual municipality.

To get you started here is Quebec City

http://donnees.ville.quebec.qc.ca/catalogue.aspx
Has many formats common to GIS (shp,KML,DWG etc).

Note: Not all municipalities have the same level of opendata, property parcel might have be sourced another way (aerial, LiDAR, imagery).

For Smaller scale boundaries you will find Natural Earth very useful.
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/

Answer (score 2):

The page is in French, but you can find a lot of geographic data on the *Ministère de l'Énergie et des Ressources naturelles*'s site:

[Répertoire des services Web et données géographiques](https://mern.gouv.qc.ca/ministere/cartes-information-geographique/repertoire-services-web-donnees-geographiques/)

Borders can be found here: [Carte générale du Québec](https://mern.gouv.qc.ca/repertoire-geographique/carte-generale-base-donnees-geographiques-administratives/)

A small scale topographic map can be found here: [Carte du relief](https://mern.gouv.qc.ca/repertoire-geographique/carte-relief-quebec/)

Toggle the sections under "Produits offerts" to access the actual files.

Answer (score 2):

[Forêt Ouverte](https://www.foretouverte.gouv.qc.ca/) has topographic (LiDAR-derived) data available to download for free. The spatial resolution of the DEMs is 1 meter, and can be downloaded by tile from the ftp link provided in Catalogue > LiDAR > Index et téléchargement > Téléchargement - LiDAR (pleine résolution). This is an ongoing southern Quebec LiDAR survey, eventually the whole southern half of Quebec should be available at that resolution. For the rest of the province, there is always the good old 1:50K [NTDB](https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/1f5c05ff-311f-4271-8d21-4c96c725c2af) maps with contour levels.

Quebec Parcel data (for the revised cadastre, called "Cadastre rénové" in French) is maintained by the MERN. It can be visualized on [Infolot](https://appli.mern.gouv.qc.ca/infolot/), but the vector data isn't free. You can refer to the web page concerning the ordering of Quebec Cadastre Lots data ([Commande des lots du cadastre du Québec](https://appli.mern.gouv.qc.ca/Infolot/Info/Commande)).

Another option for parcel data may be to contact individual municipalities or counties (MRC) and ask if they offer data extraction services for vectorial property assessment parcel boundaries (Unités d'évaluation) from their "Matrice graphique" (for a fee).